# How to put a trait Bound to elements built with document.create_element

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

Working on a minimal prototype/test program for Dom manipulation using Rust and `wasm-bindgen`.

Building the element with `document.create_element(tag)`, which returns a [`web_sys::Element`](https://docs.rs/web-sys/0.3.35/web_sys/struct.Element.html). The element is casted to specific type, depending on tag e.g. [`web_sys::HtmlButtonElement`](https://docs.rs/web-sys/0.3.35/web_sys/struct.HtmlButtonElement.html). This works and furthermore put in a small wrapper used to setup element type specific builders.

```
struct ElemSpec<T> {
    html_tag : html_const::HtmlTag<'static>,
    resource_type: std::marker::PhantomData<T>
}

impl<T : wasm_bindgen::JsCast> ElemSpec<T> {

    fn build_element(&self) -> T {
        let window = web_sys::window().expect("no global `window` exists");
        let document = window.document().expect("should have a document on window");
        let elem = document.create_element(&self.html_tag);

        let elem = match elem {
            Ok(e) => e,
            Err(error) => {
                panic!("Call to document.create_element failed with error: {:?}", error)
            },
        };
        let result = wasm_bindgen::JsCast::dyn_into::<T>(elem);
        let helement = match result {
            Ok(e) => e,
            Err(e) => {
                panic!("Cast to specific Element failed tag:{}", &self.html_tag);
            },
        };
        helement
    }
}

const BUTTON_ELEM : ElemSpec<web_sys::HtmlButtonElement> =
    ElemSpec{ html_tag: html_const::BUTTON, resource_type: std::marker::PhantomData};
```

This works, an `HtmlButtonElement` is built with:

`let buttonElement = BUTTON_ELEM.build_element();`

Now I look for a trait Bound, that restricts to elements, which could be casted from [`web_sys::Element`](https://docs.rs/web-sys/0.3.35/web_sys/struct.Element.html). E.g. `HtmlSpanElement`, `HtmlDivElement`, ..., `HtmlButtonElement`.

An additional or replacement Bound to `wasm_bindgen::JsCast` in `impl<T : wasm_bindgen::JsCast>`, could this be done?

Comment: One common bound among the bunch seems to be `AsRef<Element>`.

Comment: Thanks! Have tested, that bound restricts to these elements, great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`wasm_bindgen::JsCast::dyn_into`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/wasm_bindgen/trait.JsCast.html#method.dyn_into) documentations states it relies on `JsCast::has_type`, which in turn calls `JsCast::instanceof`. And indeed `web_sys::Element` does implement `JsCast` trait. So do the other HTML element types such as `HtmlButtonElement`.

The implementation is generated from [Web IDL](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/) files, which are the formal definition of web browser interfaces. However:

```
impl JsCast for Element {
    fn instanceof(val: &JsValue) -> bool {
        #[link(wasm_import_module = "__wbindgen_placeholder__")]
        #[cfg(all(target_arch = "wasm32", not(target_os = "emscripten")))]
        extern "C" {
            fn __widl_instanceof_Element(val: u32) -> u32;
        }
        #[cfg(not(all(target_arch = "wasm32", not(target_os = "emscripten"))))]
        unsafe fn __widl_instanceof_Element(_: u32) -> u32 {
            panic!("cannot check instanceof on non-wasm targets");
        }
        unsafe {
            let idx = val.into_abi();
            __widl_instanceof_Element(idx) != 0
        }
    }
}
```

the generated `instanceof` method calls into WebIDL native library. Since it crosses the language boundary, it can't tell us much about what these element types have in common on the Rust side.

On the other hand, `HtmlButtonElement` and others also implement [`AsRef<Element>`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.HtmlButtonElement.html#impl-AsRef%3CElement%3E) as:

```
impl AsRef<Element> for HtmlButtonElement {
    #[inline]
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &Element {
        use wasm_bindgen::JsCast;
        Element::unchecked_from_js_ref(self.as_ref())
    }
}
```

So there you have it, one common bound among them is `AsRef<Element>`. Most likely this is a conscious design decision by `web-sys` authors because it also makes sense from [WebIDL / JavaScript perspective](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement):

[image]